# Convert string range to float and return its max on GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I haven't been able to convert the array into float to get its max and add 0.1 to it and then return it in string format.

Any idea on what needs tweaking here?

```
function newVersion() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("ArquivoItens");
  var range = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow(),3).getValues();
  var editarSheet = ss.getSheetByName('EditarItem');
  var itemCode = editarSheet.getRange("W5").getValue();
  var lastVersion = [];

  var max = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < range.length; i++){
    if(range[i].indexOf(itemCode) != -1){
    lastVersion.push(parseFloat(range[i][2]));
    }
    }
    max = Math.max(lastVersion);
    return max; //to string
    Logger.log(max);
    }
```

Thanks for any light here.

Here is the working piece of code that does what the question says:

```
for (var i = 0; i < range.length; i++){
    if(range[i].indexOf(itemCode) != -1){
    lastVersion.push(parseFloat(range[i][2]));
    }
    }
    max = Math.max.apply(null, lastVersion) + .1;
    Logger.log(max.toFixed(1));
    return max.toFixed(1);
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data that you have in `range` and `W5`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### If you want to apply `Math.max()` to an array, you need to expand the values of the array into the function's arguments

So:
`max = Math.max(...lastVersion);`

Read [this](https://www.jstips.co/en/javascript/calculate-the-max-min-value-from-an-array/) for more information.

Also, `return` will finish your function execution, so any logs or other code you implement subsequently will be ignored.